# Is this hole at the corner of the foundation major issue?

Tags: water, basement, foundation, hole

I am in the process of purchasing a home. I found the perfect home but of course, I found water stains in the basement walls (mostly close to the floor). I also noticed a small hole at the corner of the foundation, about 2 to 3 inches in diameterCan this be the cause of the water seepage in the basement ? How can it be fixed.

---

Thank you for the reply. I took a picture and tried to post but won't let me cause I don't have reputation.
The sump pump is on the opposite side of the house. The hole is close to another pipe.

Comment: Did you take a picture that you can post?

Comment: Have you hired an inspector yet? If not, absolutely do that. Never buy a home without first having it inspected. This is a question you need to ask the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to ask whether the hole is for a sump pump that removes water from the basement in wet weather - it could exist specifically to prevent further water issues (such as the one that caused the water marks) in the basement, in which case, filling it in would be inadvisable.

Comment: If the sump is simply dumping water right out the foundation, it's going to have to work a lot harder since all the water it pumps out will come right back in.